# Copy items from observablearray to another observablearray

Tags: knockout.js

I have 2 observablearray. 
When I copy items from observablearray1 to observablearray2, and change value in observablearray2, in changes in observablearray1 too.

```
var viewModel = (function() {
    var
        array1 = ko.observableArray(['John', 'Joe', 'Jim']),
        array2 = ko.observableArray();

    // copy
    array2(array1());
    array2()[2] = 'Mary';
    return {
        array1: array1,
        array2: array2
    }

})();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

console.log(viewModel.array1());
console.log(viewModel.array2());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xveEP/69/

Results:
array 1
John
Joe
Mary
array 2
John
Joe
Mary

How to fix it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Knockout will still track dependencies since it is still an array with a reference in an `observableArray`. When doing `array2(array1())` , the two observables still reference the same object.

Pass a copy of the array instead (no need to explicitly copy the elements).

```
array2(array1().slice(0));
```

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nYCU/)

Alternatively, KnockoutJS shims observableArrays with their own slice method and you can call that

```
array2(array1.slice());
```

From the docs:

> slice - The slice function is the observableArray equivalent of the native JavaScript slice function (i.e., it returns the entries of your array from a given start index up to a given end index). Calling myObservableArray.slice(...) is equivalent to calling the same method on the underlying array (i.e., myObservableArray().slice(...)).

Comment: Do you have any insight on copying deeply? That is, copying observables within an observable array by value instead of by reference?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the elements of the array instead of the array itself:

```
// copy
for (var i = 0; i < array1().length; i++) {
    array2().push(array1()[i]);
}
```